# Thymeleaf Link url expression with anchor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, url, thymeleaf

I need create a url in thymeleaf with anchor. Like:

```
/import#34546
```

But the link url expression does not work.

```
<a th:href="@{import#{id}(id=${object.id}}">link</a>
```

someone get this url using thymeleaf?

I use thymeleaf with spring-boot 2.5.4.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using too many brackets.

Comment: By the way, your expression in the question is missing the closing `)` in `...(id=${object.id})}` - but that still does not evaluate to what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

Thymeleaf does not support the use of expressions for evaluating URL fragments. It assumes the fragment will be hard-coded.

Therefore I suggest you use a combination of the `@{...}` syntax for everything apart from the fragment, and then use string concatenation to build the fragment with a Thymeleaf `${...}` expression.

One example (there are other ways to do concatenation, also):

```
<a th:href="@{import} + ${'#' + object_id}">link</a>
```

This allows you to still take advantage of the features of `@{...}`, such as handling for absolute and relative URLs.

**Details**

Looking at the Thymeleaf source code for the [`StandardLinkBuilder`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/linkbuilder/StandardLinkBuilder.java) class, we can see how [URL fragments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (the `#` and its following fragment identifier) are handled.

Points to note are:

The fragment portion of the URL is extracted [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/309b9f298e03cd069a6eea526bec298cfbec4a4a/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/linkbuilder/StandardLinkBuilder.java#L160):

```
urlFragment = linkBase.substring(hashPosition);
```

The hash position is the location of a `#` in the URL string.

This substring is then removed from the URL string:

```
linkBase.delete(hashPosition, linkBase.length());
```

Later on (see [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/309b9f298e03cd069a6eea526bec298cfbec4a4a/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/linkbuilder/StandardLinkBuilder.java#L199)), after all other parameters have been processed, the urlFragment is added back to the URL, unchanged:

```
linkBase.append(urlFragment);
```

So, there is no processing of Thymeleaf expression variables for the URL fragment - it is just treated as a "hard-coded" string.

This means you can do something like this, where `#foo` is hardcoded:

```
<a th:href="@{import/{id}#foo(id=${object_id})}">link</a>
```

But you cannot do this (and get the desired result):

```
<a th:href="@{import/{id_a}#{id_b}(id_a=${object_id},id_b=${object_id})}">link</a>
```